# Создание и редактирование plist программно

Tags: ios, swift

В общем, делаю игру, в ней должно быть несколько пользователей и возможность создавать нового. Для каждого нужно где-то сохранять настройки и тд. Решил создавать для каждого нового пользователя plist, название которого будет соответствовать имени пользователя. Вопрос, как программно создать plist, и перезаписывать в нем значения?

Comment: И как же это относится к разработке игр и SpriteKit?

Comment: Json для этой задачи не лучше подойдёт (более читабельный, удобнее править руками)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания pList используется класс *[NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/)*.  PList можно создавать из объектов классов NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, and NSNumber и их комбинаций. 
Для записи pList можно использовать 2 метода:

```
+ dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:
+ writePropertyList:toStream:format:options:error:
```

Первый возвращает NSData (который можно записать в файл), второй пишет в OutputStream, который нужно связать с файлом. Вот [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html) есть пример кода.

Для превращения ваших моделей в Foundation объекты можно воспользоваться одной из библиотек, например [EasyMapping](https://github.com/EasyMapping/EasyMapping)